# How can I only list files from S3 using a wildcard pattern path?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to know if it is possible in Java to use wildcard to list all existing files according to a pattern path 
For example, if i use this pattern path

```
s3://dataai/alarms/Json/mydata/[0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]*/*_01.json
```

it should return all these files for example:

```
s3://dataai/alarms/Json/mydata/9901/2021/10/1243332_01.json
s3://dataai/alarms/Json/mydata/9912/2021/10/1245432_01.json
s3://dataai/alarms/Json/mydata/9912/2021/09/7665432_01.json
...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not support such wildcards when listing objects.

Your code would need to return *all objects* with that Prefix. Your code should then perform the wildcard check against the list of returned Keys.